# Client side onKeyUp event not firing on web page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

This is a pretty simple setup, I have no clue what gives here... I simply want a textbox in .aspx control to call a javascript onKeyUp. As the matter of fact I tried different events here without any luck. Below is .aspx (abbreviated) and the javascript. Thanks

.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NewCC.aspx.cs" Inherits="Business.Web.Invoices.NewCC" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/NewCC.js"></script>
.....

</head>
<body>
.....
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCCNumber" runat="server" Text="" MaxLength="16" Width="150" onKeyUp="PauseRecording()"></asp:TextBox>
```

NewCC.js

```
function PauseRecording()
{
    alert("in pause ");

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you ensure the js location is correct?

Comment: Are you getting a JavaScript error? I've removed ASP.NET from your question title and made it more informative, as tags don't belong in the title.

Comment: I'm getting absolutely nothing, that's what's driving me up the wall here. Must be something silly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in this way

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCCNumber" runat="server" Text="" MaxLength="16" Width="150"></asp:TextBox>
```

in page load method

```
txtCCNumber.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp", "PauseRecording();");
```

looking at the documentation I saw that TextBox has only

```
public event EventHandler TextChanged
```

so I suppose that the problem is that onKey.. event doesn't exist for `TextBox` (server side events not javascript events)

refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx) for documentation

**update**

if my previous code doesn't work (I had a working example in my project with it) try with

```
txtCCNumber.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp", "alert('test');");
```

and if now the message appear your script file is not getting looaded

Comment: Yeah, I actually had like that at first - same outcome.

Comment: Hmmm...I just checked - I do have onkeydown hooked up to a textbox in another project.

Comment: onkeydown javascript event not server side event. It is referred to you code in question

Comment: updated my answer.. let me know if you test the code with test alert. Are you getting some error from script console?

Comment: OK, upon further testing - it doesn't matter whether it's onkeyup or onKeyUp, in both cases an alert goes off if it's placed in code behind. When I have an alert in javascript , that's when I run into a problem. What can be wrong there?

Comment: You were right, faby, I moved the script from the file over to the page itself and it started to work. Thanks for your help!